# context:property-placeholder in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am new to spring framework. When I am trying to load properties files in  my xml file it is showing the following error.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [byConstructor.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 70; The prefix "context" for element "context:property-placeholder" is not bound.

Here is my my `.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:from.properties"/>
<bean id="u" class="dependenceInjection.ByConstructor">
    <constructor-arg value="101" type="int"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="java"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="impleCoach" class="dependenceInjection.ImpleCaoch">
    <property name="name" value="${value}" />
</bean>
```

from.properties

```
value=value from properties
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the `xml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:from.properties"/>

    <bean id="u" class="dependenceInjection.ByConstructor">
        <constructor-arg value="101" type="int"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="java"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="impleCoach" class="dependenceInjection.ImpleCaoch">
        <property name="name" value="${value}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Note : This xml will work. But I recommend checking your beans in the xml that you have written.

Please follow this convention for creating beans :

Example : Class : **Team**, package:**com.demo**, id = **firstletter of the class is small** , i.e, team

```
<bean id ="team" class="com.demo.Team">
</bean>
```

Comment: class name is correct <bean id="u" class="dependenceInjection.ByConstructor"> i have added a picture please check out there and suggest me

Comment: this is a tested xml. It will work. Please properly setup your project

Comment: In xsi:schemaLocation, you have not added this
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd". Add this

Comment: the xml file working properly without `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:from.properties/>` whenever i add this tag in `<beans>` tag so eclipse marked `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:from.properties"/>` as an error. Also i have added screenshot above you can check out there

Comment: ok just copy my source xml that I have provided. tell me status of the xml whether error is there or not. (The file sent is already tested on eclipse.)

Comment: it is still showing same error. after adding springframework.org/schema/mvc springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd.

Comment: Paste my source xml code and check lib folder whether you have all spring dependencies or not.

Comment: there was a spell mistake in `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` thank you @Anish B

Answer (score 0):

[byConstructor.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8H07.png) i think my xml code is correct you can check out in following picture but eclipse marked `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:from.properties"/> as an error`